# Can I overload JSoup Elements class to getElementsByTag using enum elements rather than strings?

Tags: java, enums, overloading

I'm writing something using JSoup, and this is something I've seen elsewhere,  many of the methods take strings as arguments.

This sort of things bugs me, I'd much rather use an enum value as an argument. This'd be easy to set up using the `HTML.Tag` 'enum' and the `.toString()` method.

Then in my overloaded methods I'd translate the 'enum' to string and feed it into the original method.

So I'd go from calling:

```
Elements allDivs = bodyElem.getElementsByTag("DIV");
```

Which is prone to spelling mistakes and not knowning the right tag name, etc to calling:

```
Elements allDivs = bodyElem.getElementsByTag(HTML.Tag.DIV))
```

But I can't figure how to overload `getElementsByTag` to take a `HTML.Tag` argument.

I've tried this:

```
    Element bodyElem = doc.body(){
        Elements getElementsByTag(HTML.Tag tag){
            return getElementsByTag(tag.toString());
        }
    };
```

But that doesn't work. Specifying `this.getElementsByTag` refers to the holding class (e.g. HTMLReader, which is one I wrote), and `super.getElementsByTag` refers to Object.

I'm worried that I just can't do this as Element might be final, like string in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81786/1075247) question.

So how should I go about doing this?

Comment: can't you use a Decorator/Wrapper for that class and use that instead?

Comment: @Eugene I can do but then I end up needing either 1) having something like `EnumFriendlyElement` or 2) use the same name as the package I'm overloading which means I tread the find line of competing namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSoup's Element type is not final which means you can extend it, it looks like you are trying to extend it with an anonymous inner class, however you cannot use inner classes to extend an existing object (doc.body() returns an already instantiated Element, you can't modify it).

Your options all depend on what approach you want to take and what seems to have the best cost/complexity to benefit ratio.

1.) Extend the Element class directly and cast the result of doc.body() to your new type that contains your overloaded getElementsByTag method.

2.) Just remember to call the toString() method on your enum type every time you are passing it into the existing getElementsByTag method, it's more verbose but it's either that or cast every Element to something else.

Java eschews some tools from other languages like C#'s extension methods (which would let you do exactly what you want here) for readability and maintainability, unfortunately that sometimes leads to the edge case like this where not having them may make code a little ugly.

Comment: That makes sense, and the fact that what I was trying to do would work in other situations would be why I thought it should work here. I think I'll have to stick with Option 2, option one seems a little too much for what is really a small change.